# Consulta usando Update PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql, update

Dadas las tablas:

CLIENTES (Nrocli,     NyApe,       Domicilio, Localidad, Saldocli)

FACTURAS (Nrofactura, Cliente,     Fecha)

DETALLES (Nrofactura, Renglón,     Articulo,  Cantidad,  Preciouni)

ARTICULOS(Nroartic,   Descripción, Rubro,     Stock,     Pto_reposicion, precio)

RUBROS   (Cod_rubro,  Descripción)

Se me pide Agregar la columna TOTAL en la tabla FACTURAS. Actualizar la misma con el total segun corresponda.
El problema es que esa columna total tendra los valores de la tabla detalles, mas especificamente de las columnas cantidad multiplicada por el precio, y en la tabla detalles la misma factura figura varias veces por lo que debo sumar los resultados de cantidad*precio si corresponden a la misma factura.

```
select * from facturas;
alter table facturas
drop column if exists TOTAL;
alter table facturas
add column TOTAL integer;
update facturas set TOTAL =
```

ya vi algunos tutoriales de como hacer updates pero en ninguno me muestra como hacerlos dependiendo de los valores de otra tabla, probe mil cosas y siempre me tira algun error. En resumen la nueva columna tendra el total facturado por cada factura, y esto se calcula en base a la tabla detalles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la mejor opción para este caso es que utilices un cursor.
Para comenzar te recomiendo que para la columna total utilices un tipo de dato que acepte decimales, ya que almacenarán el resultado de una multiplicación (cantidad*preciouni):

```
alter table facturas add column total numeric(12,2);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora creamos el cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cursor_while() RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    reg          RECORD;
    cur_f        CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM facturas;                 
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_f;
   FETCH cur_f INTO reg;
   WHILE( FOUND ) LOOP       
       update facturas set total = (select sum(cantidad*preciouni) from detalles where nrofactura=reg.nrofactura)
       where nrofactura=reg.nrofactura; 
       FETCH cur_f INTO reg;
   END LOOP ;
   RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Puse los siguientes datos de prueba:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ejecutar el cursor:

```
SELECT cursor_while();
```

En mi caso el resultado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.